# Programatically Add Control to ASP.NET C# Page on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to add fixtures to a particular gameweek on my asp.net c# page.

When a user clicks the add button, it should create two drop downs so they can select the home and away team. I want to be able to allow as many fixtures as the user wants to add, so therefore I need a dynamic way of adding controls to the page. Once all of the fixtures have been added, I want them all to be saved to the database.

Scrolling trough forums I have found the following method to get a control to be added programatically:

c#

```
        protected void AddTeamButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList homeTeamName = new DropDownList();
        homeTeamName.Items.Add("Arsenal");
        homeTeamName.Items.Add("Aston Villa");
        homeTeamName.ID = "homeTeam";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(homeTeamName);

        DropDownList awayTeamName = new DropDownList();
        awayTeamName.Items.Add("Arsenal");
        awayTeamName.Items.Add("Aston Villa");
        awayTeamName.ID = "awayTeam";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(awayTeamName);
    }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

This however only creates one set of controls, the second time you click add, nothing happens. It also does not create uniques IDs to access when I need to save.

Any ideas how I can solve these issues I am having?

Comment: Try giving each pair of controls unique IDs, otherwise there is no surprise they are being added only once.

Comment: I'd suggest you use a ListView control with a template that repeats itself according to the number of items in a collection. You can then by clicking your button add 1 item in the collection. The ListView control takes care of unique ids etc. Just Drag&Drop a ListView from the Toolbox, add an ItemTemplate, add a DataSource, and call DataBind(). Have a look at the MSDN page for ListView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls in asp.net are not all that easy.
You need to create them on each Post(Ideally on `Init`) till you require them on the page.
You also need to give them unique IDs.

If you want to create multiple controls, I suggest maintaining a counter in your Session and using that to loop and generate the required controls on Init.

On your `AddTeamButton_Click` you will only increment the counter and add one set of controls.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I may have to use a grid view instead, shame really ! I really don't like them

Comment: It is still better than the book-keeping that creating these controls on your own requires.